# symfony 1.0 : Error -> "The Page isn't redirected properly"

Tags: php, symfony1

I am learning symfony 1.0 and i am facing a problem continuously that page isn't redirected properly

I tried all my way but i failed in every try. Is it because of setAuthentication() or session() ?

Update: `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI


#rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.imaginamalta.com/New/ [nc]
#rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.imaginamalta.com/New/$1 [r=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  # comment the following 3 lines to allow periods in routes
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

  rewritecond %{http_host} ^http://meh.newsly.svs113/ [nc]
  rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://meh.newsly.svs113/$1 [r=301,L]

</IfModule>

# big crash from our front web controller
ErrorDocument 500 "<h2>Application error</h2>symfony application failed to start properly"
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be starting with Symfony 1.0. At the very least use 1.4 (for which support ends in November) or with Symfony2.

Comment: Thanx for reply richsage but i am having a site made in symfony 1.0 which was developed earlier by someone and i have to solve this problem as early as possible.

Comment: You need to show us something else. Like the stacktrace of the error, the related method in the action class, etc ..

Comment: I am validating a user by saving session attrinute at login time and i also authenticate that user is authenticated or not by using $sf_user->isAuthenticated() method in menu.php partial.
When i close my browser without logging out and comes back then this error occurs.

Comment: By default it should ask for login but it displays this error.And yes I also authenticates a user in every page by session attribute.Is it due to this session attribute?
How long a session attribute live defaultly if we don't destroy it?

Comment: Show us the code where you perform the authentification, the FULL error you get, etc ..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with your `.htaccess`. Try setting `AllowOverride` to `ALL`.

Comment: You are talking about SymPHony here and the thread is related to symFony :)

Comment: .htaccess file is set defaultly and i think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: j0k: can you give me some more explaination plz coz i am not getting you.

Comment: can you post your .htaccess even if its set defaultly?

Comment: here is my .htaccess file:

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  RewriteRule .* - [L]

  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
 
  rewritecond %{http_host} ^http://meh.newsly.svs113/ [nc]
  rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://meh.newsly.svs113/$1 [r=301,L]
   
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 500 "<h2>Application error</h2>symfony application failed to start properly"

Comment: the rewrite rules look unreadable to me - can you update your question? (i already added them)

Comment: Thariama : I just edited my question and put htaccess file in question.

Comment: hmm, ok can you tell me if there is anything of importance in your apache log?

Comment: Actually i don't have any idea of that Thariama.

Comment: What to put here from log file Thariama?

Comment: everything from right after you sent the last request (there should be timestamps)

Comment: The file is too big and that error only occurs at first starting of browser.After this error occur if i clear my cache memory then this error disappears.So right now i cant find that error logs in log file.

Comment: What if you clear your cookie? Is it possible to test it online (for us)?

Comment: This project is not online and i don't find any way to show you the project.And in my previous comment cache memory means firefox's cache memory.